# How to use private NTP service (instedad pool.ntp.org) in the syncronization of WSO2 MB cluster nodes?

Tags: wso2, ntp, wso2-message-broker

I am installing a **WSO2 MB** in a two node cluster. I am following the official documentation:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+Message+Broker+Profile#ClusteringtheMessageBrokerProfile-Mountingtheregistry

I have the following doubt related nodes syncronization: I have installed **ntpdate**. The documentation says to perform this command in order to create the **timesync.sh**:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

The problem is that I have no access to **pool.ntp.org** from my machines but I have the IP of an NTP service provided by the enterprise organization for which I am installing the cluster.

So can I use this IP instead **pool.ntp.org** address? Can I do something like this?

```
ntpdate INTERNAL_NTP_IP_ADDRESS
```

Is it something that can work or am I constrained to use **pool.ntp.org**?